# How to distinguish from which div event is generated

Tags: jquery

On click of the Checkbox , i am copying the same section of HTML to another div named as "**ordersdiv**"

Now the user can click on both the checkboxes that is from the **activateUiHTML** div or from **ordersdiv**  div

Right now i have a common listener for both of them as shown

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
 var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
    $("#ordersdiv").append(divdata);
});
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/18/

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: How to distinguish from which div the checkbox is clicked on ??

Comment: You want to cancel the event from ordersdiv?

Comment: do you want to get an id or a number or something?

Comment: I just need an alert that it is clicked from this particular div .

Answer (score 2):

Just add class to orders div

`<div id="ordersdiv" class="orders">`

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
    var cls = $(this).parents('div').attr('class') // based on class
    if(cls == 'activateUiHTML')
    {
    var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
    $("#ordersdiv").append(divdata);
    } 
    else{}
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/21/)

Answer (score 1):

You could add additional class to each of the divs and then based on that make desicion

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function (e) {
    if ($(this).has('.classA')) {

    } else {

    }
    //var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
    //$("#ordersdiv").append(divdata);
});
```

Cleaner solution would be to add each of div classes and then separate handlers if handling mechanisms differ

Answer (score 0):

You Check Parent to Find

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
if($(this).parent().parent().attr('id')=="clickdiv")
 {
var divdata = $("div.activateUiHTML").html();
$("#ordersdiv").append(divdata);
 }

 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/18/)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/harpreet0103/e56TY/23/)
you need to add a simple check to do that like this:

```
var id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
if(id!="ordersdiv")
```